# How to register account to "image-registry.openshift-image-registry"

Tags: openshift

### Environment

Openshift 4.3

### Question

When we push or pull the image in openshift image registry, (According to [document](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/registry/accessing-the-registry.html),) It is recommended to use `kubeadmin` account.
But don't want to use `kubeadmin` account.
So, My question is : How can I register another account to podman?

```
$ oc debug node/workernode
sh-4.2# chroot /host
```

I want to use another account instead of kubeadmin:

```
sh-4.4# podman login -u kubeadmin -p $(oc whoami -t) image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use any account which is granted "registry-viewer" or "registry-editor" role. It's mentioned it on the docs you provided either.

You are required to use other credential except "kubeadmin" default admin account using additional identity provider. Refer [Understanding identity provider configuration](https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.3/authentication/understanding-identity-provider.html) for more details.

For example, if you want to login to internal image registry using "testuser",

1. Grant required permissions to "testuser".

```
  For pulling images, for example when using the podman pull command, the user must have the registry-viewer role. To add this role:

  $ oc policy add-role-to-user registry-viewer testuser
  
  For writing or pushing images, for example when using the podman push command, the user must have the registry-editor role. To add this role:

  $ oc policy add-role-to-user registry-editor testuser
```

2. Get the token of "testuser" for using credential of the image registry.

```
  $ oc login -u testuser -p your_password

  $ oc whoami -t
  XXXXXX
```

3. Verify it whether the "testuser" can login or not.

```
  $ oc debug node/workernode
  sh-4.2# chroot /host

  sh-4.4# podman login -u testuser -p XXXXXX image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000
```

Comment: To login podman, I need to use account's token! I didn't know about that. I already tried add role to user, but I use just password to login podman. That's my mistake.... Thank you so much!